# Свой шрифт в Тильде html-блок

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Нужна помощь/совет. Мне необходимо в конструкторе сайтов https://tilda.cc/ru/, в html-блоке (Т123) использовать свой кастомный шрифт. Вот пример кода: http://maasslending.tilda.ws/font Нормально отображает шрифт только Safari. Chrome, Firefox, Opera - не отображают шрифт. Насколько я понял, эти браузеры не грузят шрифты с других доменов. А это единственный способ, как я понял, чтобы подключить свои шрифты, так как Тильда не даёт загружать файлы к себе на хостинг.

Пробовал интегрировать шрифт в код CSS с помощью base64, но Тильда такой код вообще не принимает.

Может существует способ чтобы решить мою проблему?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках сайта есть вкладка шрифты и цвета.
Как видно из картинки - Вы можете выбрать, например, шрифты из Google fonts либо загрузить свой шрифт.

Удачи!

P.S. Ваш вопрос не касается тех тегов, которые Вы перечислили. Более правильно было бы поставить тег tilda

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, оказывается действительно можно получить доспуп к этой таблице стилей со шрифтами из html-блока. Хотя рвньше я пробовал и у меня не получалось.